# Is there a way to have pacemaker resource groups failover if all floating IP resources are unavailable?

Tags: ip, pacemaker, corosync, resources

I want to have multiple floating IPs in a resource group that will only failover if all IPs cannot work. Each floating IP is on a different subnet and can be used by the application I have. If a floating IP is unavailable it will use the next available floating IP.

```
Resource Group: floating_IP

floating-IP

floating-IP2

floating-IP3
```

For example, right now if a floating-IP resource fails the whole resource group will failover to a different node. What I want is to have pacemaker failover the resource group only if all three resources are unavailable.